# How can I check a Rules condition to see if the Statuses sender and recipient are the same?

Tags: rules, status-messages

I am using "Execute custom PHP" as a condition in a Rule which is being triggered when a new [Status](https://drupal.org/project/statuses) is saved. Here is the PHP I am using, it keeps causing "Trying to get property of non-object" errors whenever I create a new status:

```
if($sender->uid == $recipient-id){
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is detect cases when the sender is sending a status message to himself so I can use an appropriate Rules action, and also the opposite:

```
if($sender->uid != $recipient-id){
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
```

I have tried a number of different variable combinations but I can't work out what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: it's basically saying that $sender is not an object yet you are trying access it in that way. What is sender and how are you passing it into the rule?

Comment: The trigger for the rule is "user saves a status" (from Statuses module), then the rules condition is set to "execute custom php" (from the builtin php filter), and finally a heartbeat activity is logged. So the php I posted above is sitting in the rules condition. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
if($status->sender == $status->recipient) {
  drupal_set_message('A match');
}
else{
  drupal_set_message('Not a match');
}
```

Rules Code

```
{ "rules_status_test" : {
    "LABEL" : "Status Test",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules", "fbss_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "statuses_save" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "if($status-\u003Esender == $status-\u003Erecipient) {\r\n  drupal_set_message(\u0027A match\u0027);\r\n}\r\nelse{\r\n  drupal_set_message(\u0027Not a match\u0027);\r\n}" } }
    ],
    "DO" : []
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I can't get this to work the way it is unfortunately. When I modify your code to look for the sender id and recipient id it then does work as intended, but I still get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error each time. I don't know if it is a token issue maybe, statuses module is notorious for this.

Comment: why do you need to look for the id? When comparing $status->sender and $status->recipient you are comparing two objects of the same type. It works on my installation. My answer doesn't use tokens it uses the variable directly. I've added a the rule which works on my clean install.